# Efficient creation of a new time series from two irregular time series with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two time irregular series, A and B, from which I want to create a new one. The resulting series should have the same index as A but the values should be based on a rolling sum over a time window of the values in B, but in relation to the indices in A.

For example:
A

```
2011-01-27 10:21:43    0
2011-01-27 10:43:29    0
2011-01-27 19:39:39    0
2011-01-27 19:55:55    0
2011-01-27 19:58:25    0
2011-01-28 15:31:58    0
2011-01-28 16:27:13    0
```

B

```
2011-01-27 10:20:29    0
2011-01-27 18:31:23    1
2011-01-27 18:45:25    1
2011-01-27 18:57:22    1
2011-01-27 19:15:25    0
```

Desired result using a 1 hour window:

```
2011-01-27 10:21:43    0
2011-01-27 10:43:29    0
2011-01-27 19:39:39    2
2011-01-27 19:56:55    1
2011-01-27 19:58:25    1
2011-01-28 15:31:58    0
2011-01-28 16:27:13    0
```

Currently I am looping through the indices of A and performing a sum over B using B[t-Hour():t].sum(). This seems very inefficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: IIUC, it seems like desired results should be `2,2,1` rather than `2,1,1`?  Regardless of that, you might try merging (but keep the existing columns as two distinct columns) and then look at the approach here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929818/arithmetic-operations-on-datetime-index-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 2,1,1 is correct, since the sum of B between 2011-01-27 18:56:55 and 2011-01-27 19:56:55 is 1. I am using datetime indexes as in the thread referenced. However, resampling is not an option since I must keep the indexes of A in the result. And I am not sure how merging would help since that would mix the indexes.